# Referencing Traditional .NET Framework from .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

We have some .NET 4.x code we need to reference from our .NET Core website. I'm able to run .NET Core on Traditional .NET as described here by [Cesar de la Torre](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/).

PROBLEM: In order to compile, it appears I need configure all project.json files in a way that all assemblies have access to the Traditional .NET framework.

QUESTION: How can I ensure that only certain .NET Core assemblies have access to .NET 4.x?

I would like my solution to look like this:

```
\WebProject <-- Requires .NET 4.x because of reference to ClassLibrary1Project
\ClassLibrary1Project <-- Requires .NET 4.x
\ClassLibrary2Project <-- Prevent .NET 4.x access 
\ClassLibrary3Project <-- Prevent .NET 4.x access
```

All the projects are .NET Core, but only `WebProject` & `ClassLibrary1Project` require access to the traditional .NET Framework. The only references are between `WebProject` and the class library projects.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know you can't. But you can deploy them as a separate service and use HTTP/MSMQ/whatever to communicate with them.

Comment: @LeonCullens You can't reference .Net 4.x from `netcoreapp1.0` applications, but you can use .Net Core tools to create .Net 4.x applications, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @svick yea, but then you're no longer running on .NET core, so you're missing the cross-platform compat and the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by using `netstandard1.x` in the `frameworks` section in project.json for libraries that shouldn't have access to .Net 4.x and using `net4xx` for libraries that should.

Make sure to use high enough version of `net`, so that you can reference the `netstandard` you used.